# Spawning a pthread has drastic change to core dump behavior

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, glibc, coredump

Below is a small program, which uses mmap to "allocate" 20GB of virtual address space, and then segfaults.  There are two behaviors that can be controlled independently (via cmd line arguments): the first causes the application to actually write to each of the 20GB; the second causes the application to spawn a pthread on startup.  So there are 4 ways the program can be run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define DELAY 3
#define THREAD_DELAY 1
#define TIMES 20
#define GB 1024*1024*1024


void* thread_run(void* name){
    while(1){
        sleep(THREAD_DELAY);
    }
}


void thread_start(char* name) {
    pthread_t thread;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_run, (void*)name);

    if(ret){
        printf("failure spawing thread [%d]\n", ret);
        exit(-1);
    }
}


int write_to_memory = 0;
int start_thread = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int     i;
    void**  address_array = malloc(TIMES * sizeof(void*));
    int*    ptr = (int*)0;

    printf("PID is %d\n", getpid());

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "write_to_memory") == 0) write_to_memory = 1;
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "start_thread") == 0) start_thread = 1;
    }

    printf("write_to_memory = %d\n", write_to_memory);
    printf("start_thread = %d\n", start_thread);


    if(start_thread){
        thread_start("OTHER_THREAD");
    }

    sleep(DELAY);
    for(i = 0; i < TIMES; i++){
        address_array[i] = mmap(NULL, GB, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if(address_array[i] == MAP_FAILED){
            printf("mmap failed");
            exit(-2);
        }
    }

    if(write_to_memory){
        sleep(DELAY);
        for(i = 0; i < TIMES; i++){
            memset(address_array[i], 0, GB);
        }
    }

    sleep(DELAY);
    *ptr = 123;
    return *ptr;
}
```

Running the program all 4 ways, I've seen something very weird - for three of the four ways the program can be run, the core dump will be ~20 GB in size; however, if I spawn a thread, but don't write to the allocated memory, the core dump is only 11 MB in size.  I cannot explain this behavior, and was wondering if this was expected.

First, some details about the environment:

```
[user@machine coredump]$ uname -a
Linux machine.domain 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[user@machine coredump]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

[user@machine coredump]$ /lib/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.
        Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
```

And now the output

```
_____________________
PID is 16012
write_to_memory = 0
start_thread = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
-rw------- 1 user group 21G Mar 14 22:57 core.16012
_____________________
PID is 16201
write_to_memory = 0
start_thread = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
-rw------- 1 user group 11M Mar 14 22:57 core.16201
_____________________
PID is 16234
write_to_memory = 1
start_thread = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
-rw------- 1 user group 21G Mar 14 22:58 core.16234
_____________________
PID is 16425
write_to_memory = 1
start_thread = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
-rw------- 1 user group 21G Mar 14 22:59 core.16425
```

Is this the expected behavior?  If so, does using pthreads imply that there is a "smarter" default segfault handler that realizes that the memory allocated hasn't been touched and therefore doesn't need to be dumped?

Comment: Why do you want a segfault / coredump in the first place?

Comment: Just to get it straight: You're not asking about the crash (segmentation fault) but about the core dump size?

Comment: I'm actually trying to debug an issue where a native library called by a java program segfaulted.  That lead to this.

Comment: Yes. I want to know why the core dump in that one case doesn't include the whole of the address pace.  I know why this program crashed :)

Comment: Here's some core size data from kernel 4.4.0-66/gcc 5.4.0/glibc 2.23 (x86_64). Neither option: 425984 bytes; write only: 21475262464 bytes; thread only: 8818688 bytes; both options: 21483655168 bytes. To my eyes this behavior appears to vary by kernel/glibc version. You might get an answer but it seems like it might be an outdated one.

Comment: This appears to be gcc specific. With clang on Linux, I get a small core dump with writing off, threads on (and even smaller with no threading). Interestingly, on MacOS using gcc (clang in disguise, with gcc options), produces large core dumps in all four cases. Finally, compiling with -O3 for gcc on Linux, produces small core dumps when not writing to the allocated memory.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368: Are you sure the `mmap()` calls succeeded in all cases? It is likely dependent on the amount of memory installed; default thread stack size is usually quite large, and just might be enough in some cases cause the `mmap()` to fail (due to resource limits exceeded, or due to RAM+SWAP heuristic check) only when a thread was created. Only a check would tell, but alas, you omit it.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - mmap succeeds.  I edited the code to make it exit on failure, but previously, this was observed via top.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368: I cannot duplicate your results (kernel 4.4.0 on x86-64, gcc 4.8, gcc 5.4, or clang-3.8). Could you change the `*ptr = ..` to `raise(SIGSEGV)`, and add C code to dump `/proc/self/maps` just before that? That output would describe the mappings, and comparing them would tell us whether the significant difference is in the actual process memory mappings, or in the cores dump only.

Answer (score 0):

The generic implementation of MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE is to create a potential mapping, rather than a real one.   The potential mapping is CopyOnWrite from (logically) /dev/zero.   There is no need to create it because it can be created at any time from a page of zeroes.   Sometimes the acronym ZeroFillOnDemand is associated with this

As soon as you write any value to the page, your program will fault and an actual page will be added to your address space.
At this point, the only source of that page is your program image.   So, the system, to conserve and or re-purpose fast RAM, might store it on swap; your image remains the sole source.

When it comes to core dumping, there are typically many regions (segments) in your process image that consists of potential mappings.  The stack, for instance, is often a huge area with very little used.  Coredump wisely chooses to only insert these single-source elements, and makes references for the rest.

Depending upon your system, you might notice that the program text and shared libraries are also not part of your core image.  You can usually test for this by finding a read only string in your program, and search for it using `strings core | fgrep 'your special string here'`.   The string for getopt() is often a good search candidate.